# Working with modules on MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I need to repeat a string n number of times on my wiki.

It looks like I can do that using [Module:String](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Module:String)

`{{#invoke:String|rep|hello|3}}`

But instead of getting `hellohellohello` I get `{{#invoke:String|rep|hello|3}}`

Do I need to install or turn on modules? I'm familiar with MediaWiki extensions but I've never come across modules before and can't find any documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to install [Extension:Scribunto](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto) — that's what creates the Module namespace, the #invoke function, and Lua modules in general on a wiki.

Then you should be able to import modules from mediawiki.org etc. and use them locally.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't terribly care about parsing performance / don't use large numbers of repeats you can do something hacky like

```
<!-- Template:Repeat -->
{{#ifexpr:{{{2}}}|{{{1}}}{{repeat|{{{1}}}|{{#expr:{{{2}}}-1}}}}}}
```

or

```
<!-- Template:Repeat -->
{{#switch: {{{2}}}
| 0 =
| 1 = {{{1}}}
| 2 = {{{1}}}{{{1}}}
| 3 = {{{1}}}{{{1}}}{{{1}}}
...
```